# php Curl loop to download images from a directory

Tags: php, loops, curl

I wanted to download images from an api, it returns a type of '.jpg' when you access the url like this.

```
https://www.foo.com/getimage.php?id=??
```

I found out that the script accepts an encoded `id`, but with `base64_encode` only, so I try doing it this way.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
 $ch = curl_init();
 $id = base64_encode($i);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.foo.com/getimage.php?id=$id");
 if(curl_exec($ch)===false){
   file_put_contents('downloads/' . base64_decode($id) . '.jpg', $ch);
 }
}
curl_close($ch);
```

What do you think is my mistake.

Comment: Does the file exist `downloads/__base64__.jpg`? Or, it never gets written? Usually you need some additional `CURLOPT` for `HTTPS` type connection.

Comment: it never gets written.

Comment: Can you try `http://www.foo.com/` or it requires SSL?

Comment: it sends me back to `https`, when i access `http`

Comment: You may also try, as an alternative to `curl`, [`file_get_contents()`](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents)

Comment: basically what I have above is correct? but without additional opt?

Answer (score 0):

This will work with `HTTP` connection. You will need some additional settings to work with `HTTPS`.

Some important notes are commented in the code.

```
<?php

for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $id = base64_encode($i);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.foo.com/getimage.php?id=$id");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // return data as string

    // disable peer verification
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

    // disable host verification
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE); 

    // spoof a real browser client string
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)"); 
    $output = curl_exec($ch); // capture data into $output variable

    if( $output != false){
        file_put_contents('downloads/' . base64_decode($id) . '.jpg', $output );
    }
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

> CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER
>
> TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of
>   curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.
>
> CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER
>
> FALSE to stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate. Alternate
>   certificates to verify against can be specified with the
>   CURLOPT_CAINFO option or a certificate directory can be specified with
>   the CURLOPT_CAPATH option.
>
> CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER
>
> FALSE to stop cURL from verifying the certificate was issued to the
>   entity we are connected to.
>
> http://www.php.net/curl_setopt